# Scan dynamic library dependencies of an executable

Tags: dynamic, shared-libraries

I'd like to get a list of the dynamic libraries that an executable needs to load in order to run. I want to do this programmatically (i.e., I'm not asking about running `ldd`). I see various tools like [libtool](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libtool.html), but it's unclear if it's possible to use them for this; and if yes, then how.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is highly OS-specific, and you didn't say which OS you are interested in.

Assuming you are interested in `ELF`, you can read `.dynamic` section of the executable, looking for entries with `.d_tag == DT_NEEDED`. The `.d_ptr` of these entries will contain offset into `.dynstr` section, with the name of required shared library. You can see decoded version of this by running `readelf -d a.out`.

Once you know what libraries are required, you'll have to replicate `ld.so`s search rules to actually find them (this will be surprisingly complicated to do in general), and then repeat the process for each library in turn.

> Are there libraries that support doing this correctly?

Any such library would soon get out of date, unless it's part of the loader itself. And this functionality *is* provided by the loader via `ldd`.

So you should probably think twice about avoiding `ldd` (what's wrong with it anyway?)

Comment: I am mostly interested in Linux, although OS X would be nice too. Given that the rules for dealing with `ld.so` are complicated, and scanning `.dynamic` section is non-trivial either, are there libraries out there that support doing this correctly?